# Dynamic React Select Menu Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm "new-ish" to React. I'm trying to create a custom component that will display a list of items in a select menu. The user will be able to choose an option from the menu. Once completed, there is an "Add" button underneath that, when clicked, would show another select menu populated by the remaining, unselected options of the first select menu. This would ideally continue to happen with each subsequent click of the Add button until there is only one option left.

I've created the below code that displays the initial select menu but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around where to go with this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Row, Col, Button, FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.props = props;
        this.state = {
            fruits: [
                { selected: false, fruit: 'Banana', value: 'banana' },
                { selected: false, fruit: 'Apple', value: 'apple' },
                { selected: false, fruit: 'Orange', value: 'orange' }
            ]
        };

        this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    _handleClick(event) {
    }

    _handleChange(option) {
        // this.setState({ value: option, selected: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid>
                    <Row>
                        <SelectMenu data={this.state.fruits} onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this)} />
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={12}>
                            <p>
                                <Button href="#" onClick={this._handleClick}>Add</Button>
                            </p>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SelectMenu extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: undefined
        };
    }

    _handleChange(event) {
        this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        const unselected = this.props.data.filter(fruit => fruit.selected == false);

        return (
            <Col sm={3}>
                <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect">
                    <ControlLabel>Select</ControlLabel>
                    <FormControl componentClass="select" placeholder="select" onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.value}>
                        {this.props.data.map((option, index) => {
                            return <option key={index} value={option.value}>{option.location}</option>;
                        })};
                    </FormControl>
                </FormGroup>
            </Col>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

This doesn't work. I'm hoping for someone to start me on the right road to creating this.

Comment: Can you elaborate by what you mean when you say "does't work"? You pass the `_handleChange` to `onChange` which gets called but the `setState` is commented out in your `_handleChange` function. Can you by chance creating a jsFiddle?

Comment: When I say it doesn't work, I mean it doesn't work in the manner I'm looking for. It does render the select element but the _handleChange function, even with the setState method uncommented doesn't help with the functionality I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a rather broad question, therefore my answer might not be exactly what you're looking for. And there are a few to many mistakes in the code you've provided for me to give specific changes that will make your code work, but I'll give you some example code that might put you on the right track.

Firstly here is an example of adding new items to be rendered. Notice how the button adds items to state.

```
class AddingItems extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }
  handleClick(){ /*Add items to state*/
    let newItem = <div>Item</div>;
    this.setState({items: this.state.items.concat([newItem])});
  }
  render(){
    return <div>
      {this.state.items /*render items from state*/}
       <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Add item!</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

---

Secondly I would suggest changing your 'data-class' from an array to a map, fruits would then look something like this:

```
fruits: {
            banana: { selected: false, fruit: 'Banana'},
            apple: { selected: false, fruit: 'Apple'},
            orange: { selected: false, fruit: 'Orange'}
        }
```

That way you can access them by `this.state.fruits.banana` or `this.state.fruits["banana"]`.